# Understanding Oil Certifications

Tags: oil

I am trying to figure out what certification VW's Certs translate into as API, if that's even possible?

Looking for oil for a '08 2.0T Passat, and it looks like it's calling for VW 502 cert.

Some oils clearly say VW 502 right on them... That's great... But almost all oils will list a API cert.

Looking on the boards finds "tons" of people "running" T6 in their gas engines. Subaru-world tends to love it, too, as well as many cycle communities.

Can someone explain why or why not T6 isn't ok?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See this, it is their own certification standard so it will not translate directly to API.....https://www.oilspecifications.org/articles/vw_motor_oil_specifications_explained.php

Comment: This lack of VW certs does not mean there are not better oils out there.

Comment: It really annoys me when manufacturers do this - it's just to try and force you to buy their own consumables instead of generic ones. I had the same thing with coolant in my Subaru...

Comment: [BobIsTheOilGuy website](http://www.bobistheoilguy.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=1239693#Post1239750) claims: **VW 502.00 Oil for high performance gasoline engines without extended oil fill change interval (15000 km – 1 year), HTHS viscosity min. 3.5 mPa-s, ACEA A3 + additional VW tests** ... not sure if that helps. I agree with @NickC here ... PITB.